# dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant ERROR

Tags: r, lidr

I am calculating metrics with `lidR`package with the command `grid_metrics` applied to a `catalog`

```
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 0
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 0
opt_filter(ctg)       <- "-drop_z_above 50 -drop_z_below -1"
opt_output_files(ctg) <- paste(wd, "metrics/*_metrics", sep = "")

#opt_stop_early(ctg) <- FALSE #can be used if neccesary

#.options
opt <- list(raster_alignment = sqrt(250))

#METRICS CALCULATION
get_metrics = function(chunk)
{
  las = readLAS(chunk)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)

  if (area(las) <  sqrt(250)) {return(NULL)}                    #to avoid very small lasfiles that might have too few points
  else {
    metrics <- grid_metrics(las, ~stdmetrics_z.lasR(Z), sqrt(250), start=c(-0.2026,0))
    return(metrics)
  }
}
metrics <- catalog_sapply(ctg, get_metrics, .options = opt)
```

and some tiles give me an error which is:

```r
metrics <- catalog_sapply(ctg, get_metrics, .options = opt)
#> |======                           | 7%
#> suggested tolerance minimum: 1 
#> |======                           | 8%
#> An error occurred when processing the chunk 145. Try to load this chunk with:
#>   chunk <- readRDS("C:\Users\jaca\AppData\Loca\Temp\Rtmpc51D7l/chunk145.rds")
#>   las <- readLAS(chunk)
#> dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant
```

It has happened to me before and I discovered that the tiles that retrieve the error normaly are very small and/or are not wall-to-wall together to the adjacent tiles. Because these tiles are not really relevant (they appear on edges of study area(see image)) the way I manage to "solve" my problem was to make a filter to only apply the function to those tiles bigger than certain area or to indicate `opt_stop_early(ctg) <- FALSE` but some times the first approach is not enough and the second one is not the best as if there are other errors they will be compiled.
Can someone explain me what is happening and if there is a way of solving it?

[image]

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example. How are we supposed to guess what is in `get_metrics()`? What is the output of `get_metrics()` on this chunk only? Have you tried to load the chunk as mentioned in the message?

Comment: According to a quick google search the error seems to be related to `SpatialPixelDataFrame`. My guess is that there is a single pixel or a single line of pixels in the chunk 145. If I'm correct an update to the version 2.2.3 could solve the problem because multilayered rasters are built more robustly. But it is just a guess because you did not provide enough information to understand the trouble.

Comment: I id not think the code would be relevant. I updated the version of  lidR and seems to work fine although there is a warning when the `catalog_sapply` is run: `The original tiling pattern does not match with the resolution 15.8113883008419. Chunks were extended to avoid partial pixels.`

Comment: Yes code matter. At least to know what is the output of your function. The new message aims to inform the user of the behavior but the behavior was already the same in former versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that happen when building a multilayer raster with too few pixels (e.g. a single pixel or a single row/column of pixels) You can use a buffer as a workaround but from the package version 2.2.3 the multilayer rasters are build more robustly and should support more limit cases like that.

That being said, why are you using `catalog_apply()` to run `grid_metrics()` and not just `grid_metrics()`? `lidR`'s functions already take care of everything for you.

```r
metrics <- grid_metrics(ctg, ~stdmetrics_z.lasR(Z), sqrt(250), start=c(-0.2026,0))
```

For example in your example you missed to put the origin in `.options`

```r
opt <- list(
  list(
    raster_alignment = sqrt(250),
    start = c(-0.2026,0)
))
```

Comment: I am using `catalog_apply()` because it does not run `grid_metrics()` when I indicate that the function to be used is `stdmetrics_z.lasR(Z)`, a slightly modified version of the `lidR` `stdmetrics_z`. The error that appears when I try to run only `grid_metrics()` exactly as you indicate in your answer is "Error: could not find function "stdmetrics_z.lasR`". I created a package where to load my function from but it appears that it does not find it

Comment: Okay, I tried `> metrics <- grid_metrics(norm, ~JaimeScrypts::stdmetrics_z.lasR(Z), sqrt(250), start=c(-0.2026,0))` and it does not show the error now. It seems to be working. I will edit this comment with the result

Comment: Interesting. Maybe this should be reported if reproducible.

Comment: Checking the results I can say it works this way: `> metrics <- grid_metrics(norm, ~JaimeScrypts::stdmetrics_z.lasR(Z), sqrt(250), start=c(-0.2026,0))`